# why can i use java.util.Scanner on an instance that implemented the path interface

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

i am pretty new in programming so if i dont use all the time all the proper terms, please forgive me :).

//////

I am doing some exercises to learn java and I was learning about the Scanner class and in the java api it says:
**" A scanner can read text from any object which implements the Readable interface."**

In the exercise i have to create a new Scanner object like this:

Path path = Paths.get("C:\myfolder\readme.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(path);

I understood that the Paths.get() method gives me an instance which implemented the Path interface and can therefore become a Path reference/is a Path instance.
But when i look in the java.Path api i cannot find that it implemented the interface Readable.
Is there a way to check if the class implemented the Readable interface?
(i tried already isinstanceof, which didnt work and gave me no answer)
How can i find out if my path-reference points to an object which implemented the Readable interface so i can use it in my Scanner. I am confused because i cannot see the Path object has implemented Readable, so how can i use it then in the Scanner?

/////

An additional question related to that question is:

I also realized if you create a File object, the File class also didnt implement the Readable Interface. So why can i read with a Scanner from a File??? What did i miss here?
It seems there are classes you can use for the Scanner who didnt implement Readable interface ( according to java api). This seems odd to me as the API demands different.

Comment: `Scanner` provides a constructor which accepts `Path` - [`Scanner(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.nio.file.Path)) - this might be a special edge case which provides a specific implementation for `Path`.  This basically creates `InputStream` from the `Path` internally.  Without having one of the devs available, I would "suspect" it's designed as a convince in order to support the Paths API over the older `File`s API.  Personally, I don't think `Scanner` should support either directly, but that's me

Answer (score 0):

You only need to know the constructors to use the Scanner class.  But if you are curious to know why the Scanner can take a file even though it's not a Readable object, you will have to look into the code of the SCanner class.

For example, the Scanner class has a constructor that takes a File object.  A File object is not a real file, just wrapper of a String of the path to the a file.  The scanner uses the File object to create an input stream and get a ReadableByteChannel.  The ReadableByeChannel will get passed to another constructor which call makeReadable.  See the code below.

In summary, the Scanner will create a Readable object from File, Path, and InputStreams, String and so on.

```
    public Scanner(File source) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this((ReadableByteChannel)(new FileInputStream(source).getChannel()));
    }

    private static Readable makeReadable(ReadableByteChannel source,
                                         CharsetDecoder dec) {
        return Channels.newReader(source, dec, -1);
    }
```